# htaccess with 301 redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to do a simple redirection 301

I want to redirect this uri 
http://www.blabla.com/test to http://www.blabla/azerty

My problem is I have some uri like http://www.blabla/test/post-123 ,http://www.blabla/test/somethingelese and I want to keep them I don't want to rewrite them

This is I put in my htacess I know it is wrong

```
redirect 301 /test http://www.blabla.com/azerty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with redirect match with end `$` anchor.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /test$ http://www.blabla.com/azerty
```